# stackapplet and Google account

Tags: support, stackapplet

I am trying to use Stack-Applet for Ubuntu ([http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/11/stackapplet-1-4-released-ubuntu-indicator/](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/11/stackapplet-1-4-released-ubuntu-indicator/%29)) and I have registered on Stack Overflow using my Google account. I guess that's why I cannot use this applet in full - it does not show threads/topics but just redirects me to the Stack Overflow page where I can see last answers to my questions.

1. Is my Google account related to this problem?
2. Could I re-register as a pure user without losing my current account info?

Answer (score 2):

As the creator and lead programmer for StackApplet, I'll try to answer your question.

> my Google-account, is it related issued to this problem?

No, StackApplet does not use any form of authentication - you simply need to know your user ID on a given site in order to add it to the application.

> could I re-register as pure user without loosing the my current account info?

There is no need to re-register - your current account can be used with StackApplet by simply entering your user ID into the preferences page.

Keep in mind that StackApplet is only a notification tool - it will tell you when your reputation changes, when you receive a comment, or when an answer is posted to one of your questions.